# How to modify and upload .csv file in azure using C#?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, export-to-csv

I have a function that takes a .csv file from the user and stores it in Azure.
The .csv file contains 2 columns ("Slashtag" and "URL"). I want to take this .csv file uploaded by the user and add another 3rd column in it and some data in that 3rd column and then again store it in my azure and generate a link to this new modified CSV using C# .NET.

Comment: So where exactly is the problem? Which of these things are you unable to do or stuck at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Azure Function with a blob storage trigger. When you upload a CSV file to the blob storage the function will fire. In the implementation of your function you read and modify the CSV, persist it to the blob storage and generate the link.